# Power Query Source=Folder.Files - dealing with empty sub-folder error

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm trying to import all files in a folder or its numerous sub-folders.
Problem is that the first source step is throwing up an error at the first occurence of a sub-folder containing no files,  and no further files details are imported into the query.

How can I amend the import `Let Source = Folders.Files("\\super secret ninja project.."")` so that it ignores any sub-folders with no contents or simply carries on importing if it encounters such an error?

Error message is *"The operation failed because the source database does not exist, the source table does not exist or because you do not have access to the source data"*

I've tested by manually removing the first sub folder I encountered that threw up the error,  and the query does indeed import further file details after removing but then again errors on the next sub-folder.
There are too many empty sub-folders to manually delete them all, and I can't control that there wouldn't be any further going forward either.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with files on my own computer. eg: path  like `Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ron\Documents")` will return all the files, skipping over empty folders.  Not sure why a UNC path would work differently.

Comment: hm, thats strange - the actual folder.files location is the network path for a shared drive,  and i'm using the \\ukstore01 etc rather than the drive letter "W:",  perhaps that might be the cause of the issue

Comment: I'm testing now with drive letter than network path, hasn't errored yet so seems it is working (it would have normally errored by now)